# How did this user asked 2 questions in 5 minutes?

Tags: support, asking-questions

AFAIK a user is allowed to ask questions only once in 20 minutes, but this user asked two questions in just five minutes.

[image]

The questions are
[Differences between restricted repositories and partner repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496294/)
[What are the differences between "precise" and "precise-updates" and "precise-backports"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496295/)

Was this because he has 3k+ rep, or because of his tags, or a bug?

Comment: It appears to me that there is no such limit, at least for 3k+ users.

Comment: In fact one question is asked at `2014-07-11 07:54:28` and the other at `2014-07-11 07:59:52`. Thus in fact, it's more than 5 minutes. It's 5 minutes and 24 seconds. What is the restriction? One question per 5 minutes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rate limits are all explained in [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/203101) on the main meta. I am reproducing the relevant part here:

> ### Asking
>
> - Users < 125 rep, 20 minutes (90 minutes on [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256323/questions-are-now-rate-limited-to-1-per-90-minutes))
>
>   - Users limited by [Anti-Recidivism System](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/165773), one question
>     per week
> - Users < 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 60 seconds
> - Users > 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 30 seconds
> - On Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and Math (not active on all other sites)
>
>   - maximum of 6 questions per day
>   - [maximum of 50 questions per 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217/13295)

As you can see, there is no limit for users of >125 rep, they only thing that happens is that they trip a captcha request if they ask more than once per minute.

There is no limit at 5 minutes. In fact, for most sites, there is no limit on the number of questions that can be asked at all.

Comment: Just one more thing, when was this implemented? I am sure(99.99%) I saw the 20min limitation well after crossing 125rep, so this must be implemented not to far in history.

Comment: @RegisteredUser no idea. Check the revision history on that meta post I linked to.